# Why is Scrapy spider not loading?

Tags: scrapy

I am a little new to the Scraping domain and was able to manage the following piece of code for my spider:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'thesentientspider.settings')
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from urlparse import urljoin
from thesentientspider.items import RestaurantDetails, UserReview
import urllib
from scrapy.conf import settings
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

#MONGODB Settings
MongoDBServer=settings['MONGODB_SERVER']
MongoDBPort=settings['MONGODB_PORT']

class ZomatoSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'zomatoSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['zomato.com']
    CITY=["hyderabad"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.zomato.com/%s/restaurants/'  %cityName for cityName in CITY
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        BASE_URL=get_base_url(response)
```

However, when i try to launch it through the **scrapy crawl zomatoSpider** command, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 131, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 76, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 138, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 43, in run
    spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/command.py", line 33, in crawler
    self._crawler.configure()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/crawler.py", line 40, in configure
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 35, in from_crawler
    sm = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 31, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 23, in __init__
    self._load_spiders(module)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 26, in _load_spiders
    for spcls in iter_spider_classes(module):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scrapy/utils/spider.py", line 21, in iter_spider_classes
    issubclass(obj, BaseSpider) and \
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Could anyone please point out the root cause and suggest modification for the same via a code snippet?

Comment: Is this the whole code of your spider? You have a syntax error there on the line with `start_urls` definition. Do you have other spiders n the dirctory?

Comment: @alecxe You mean the extra comma? Editing that out. Its not in the source code. Must have come when i posted the snippet. This is the initial portion of the code...the remaining part is mostly parse definitions. The thing is, i was able to start the crawler earlier, but when i added the code for handling MongoDB connections (MongoClient, settings, et al) it broke and i am unable to understand why.

Comment: Ok, the code you have provided looks ok to me. Do you have other spiders in the directory?

Comment: @alecxe Nopes, this is the only one. You think its got something to do with the deprecated way of accessing settings i have used?

Comment: I don't think so, could you show the whole spider, so I can run it myself?

Comment: @alecxe Yup, thesentientspider/thesentientspider/spiders/zomato_spider.py :: http://pastebin.com/0UTtrGCe

thesentientspider/thesentientspider/settings.py :: http://pastebin.com/3SmvgLd4

Comment: Btw, why are you instantiating mongodb connection in the spider. Usually, it's a good idea to have a database pipeline and pass scrapy `Items` from the spider to the pipeline. Or, alternatively, you can instantiate mongodb connection in the `__init__` method of the spider. Can you check both options? Do you see any errors?

Comment: I mean that it doesn't look good that you have all of this database stuff happening inside the spider. Spiders are used for scraping the data from web pages. All these mongo-related lines should go to the pipeline anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self):

        MongoDBServer=settings['MONGODB_SERVER']
        MongoDBPort=settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        database=settings['MONGODB_DB']
        rest_coll=settings['RESTAURANTS_COLLECTION']
        review_coll=settings['REVIEWS_COLLECTION']

        client=MongoClient(MongoDBServer, MongoDBPort)
        db=client[database]
        self.restaurantsCollection=db[rest_coll]
        self.reviewsCollection=db[review_coll]
```

This is the code that i added in to make it work. Hope it helps.